# Assign unique file names when unloading data to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3

I would like to assign files unique names when they are unloaded from SnowFlake to S3 using a PowerShell script:

```bsh
#get table names and assign them to $table_names
#using datdev connection to get them from datdev_db.dev_load
$current_date = Get-Date
$current_date = $current_date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

$table_names = snowsql -c dwhdev_db -q "select 'COPY INTO s3://<bucket_name>/' 
    || '$current_date' || '/e1 FROM ' || table_schema || '.' || table_name 
    || ' storage_integration = s3_int file_format = (format_name = 
    public.backup_to_s3_csv_format);' from 
        (select table_schema, table_name from information_schema.tables where 
            table_schema = '<schema_name>')"

#remove header/footer
$table_names = $table_names[5..($table_names.length-4)]

#trim pipes and spaces
$table_names = $table_names.trim("|")
$table_names = $table_names.trim()

#iterate through the array
foreach($item in $table_names){
    snowsql -c dwhdev_db -q "select '$item' from dual" -o friendly=false -o header=false -o quiet=true -o remove_comments=true -o output_format=plain -o output_file=copy_<schema_name>_tables.ps1
    snowsql -c dwhdev_db -f copy_<schema_name>_tables.ps1
}
```

Running the script produces the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\samst\Documents> ./snowsql_copy_tables.ps1
* SnowSQL * v1.2.2
Type SQL statements or !help
+---------------+-------------+--------------+
| rows_unloaded | input_bytes | output_bytes |
|---------------+-------------+--------------|
|         20002 |    19233082 |      1554279 |
+---------------+-------------+--------------+
1 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 2.143s
Goodbye!
* SnowSQL * v1.2.2
Type SQL statements or !help
001030 (22000): SQL compilation error:
Files already existing at the unload destination: s3://<bucket_name>/2019-12-26/. Use overwrite option to force unloading.
001030 (22000): SQL compilation error:
Files already existing at the unload destination: s3://<bucket_name>/2019-12-26/. Use overwrite option to force unloading.
Goodbye!
* SnowSQL * v1.2.2
Type SQL statements or !help
001030 (22000): SQL compilation error:
Files already existing at the unload destination: s3://<bucket_name>/2019-12-26/. Use overwrite option to force unloading.
001030 (22000): SQL compilation error:
Files already existing at the unload destination: s3://<bucket_name>/2019-12-26/. Use overwrite option to force unloading.
001030 (22000): SQL compilation error:
Files already existing at the unload destination: s3://<bucket_name>/2019-12-26/. Use overwrite option to force unloading.
Goodbye!
* SnowSQL * v1.2.2
Type SQL statements or !help
```

How can I modify that PowerShell script to output a unique file name on every run?

Comment: Do the filenames need to be sequential/timestamped or would you be okay using a random ID or GUID?

Answer (score 0):

It would all depend on how you want to differentiate your files. If you want a different filename for each run, you could generate a GUID for each file to be uploaded using the below snippet ([reference](https://blog.davidjwise.com/2012/02/22/creating-guids-in-powershell/)):

```
# Create a new GUID
$Id = [GUID]::NewGuid()
```

It's up to you how you want to integrate this with your file name conventions... but it might look something like this:

```
#iterate through the array
foreach($item in $table_names){
    $unique_name = [GUID]::NewGuid()
    snowsql -c dwhdev_db -q "select '$item' from dual" -o friendly=false -o header=false -o quiet=true -o remove_comments=true -o output_format=plain -o output_file=${unique_name}.ps1
    snowsql -c dwhdev_db -f ${unique_name}.ps1
    }
```

Alternatively, if you use a longer timestamp, precise enough that you don't foresee the script being run twice within the increment, you could use that to differentiate folders/filenames.

Comment: Thanks @nsprenkle, I don't want unique files.  I want a unique S3 bucket name for each run. I'm trying what you suggest, iterating through to generate a new GUID to append to my S3 bucket name. The only change to the code is:
  
`# Create a new GUID
$id = [GUID]::NewGuid()

#iterate through the array
foreach($item in $id){
    $unique_name = [GUID]::NewGuid()
    $table_names = snowsql -c dwhdev_db -q "select 'COPY INTO s3://<bucket_name>/' || '$current_date' || '-' || '$unique_name'

[snip]`

but I still only get one GUID with that code where I want a new GUID for each run.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting.  I tried ending the line with 2 spaces and back ticks around the code.  Not coming out right.

Comment: Does "new GUID for each run" mean "each time I run this script" or "each table"?